# Excel userform VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to change a label accordingly a combination of cells.
For example I have 5 Column that I can show in my label. But I'll show just the columns that is not blank.
Label.Caption = Column A, Column C and Column D
How I can express this in VBA in Label.Caption?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are using ActiveX Controls if you are using Labels and want to change the name dynamically. In the properties pane, you just change the name to something meaningful and you can reference it just as you said, labelName.Caption = value or labelName.Caption = Range("A1").value or something equivalent.

Comment: You don't need ActiveX controls, unless you count the Forms as ActiveX Controls. There are 2 different Forms, and they behave differently and have different toolbars. For the first it is .caption, where for the other it is .text

Comment: Are you trying to display data from multiple rows in that column? If so, is there a reason it must be a label, instead of a textbox formatted to look like a label? If there is only one non-blank row in the column, is there ever a time when multiple columns need to be displayed in the label?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Sub Henrique()
    Dim labelRow As Long
    Dim labelText As String
    Dim i As Long
    labelRow = 1
    For i = 1 To 5
        If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(labelRow, i)) Then
            labelText = labelText & Sheet1.Cells(labelRow, i) & " "
        End If
    Next
    labelText = Trim$(labelText)
    With UserForm1.Label1
        .Caption = labelText
    End With
End Sub
```